# Test for paired proportion data

Tags: proportion, paired-data, manova, compositional-data

I want to test for differences in the connectivity of two different brain regions (A and B) measured in 100 subjects. For each brain region, I have measured connectivity to 150 other brain regions (i.e., for each subject, there are 150 connectivity values for brain region A, and 150 connectivity values for brain region B). Each connectivity value is expressed as a *proportion* out of the total connectivity measured for brain region A or B (i.e, the 150 connectivity values  sum to a total 100% for region A and B separately).

So my data is 100 (subjects) x 2 (brain regions A and B) x 150 (connectivity to 150 other brain regions).

my questions are:

1. what would be the most appropriate statistical test of whether the *overall connectivity* pattern to the 150 brain regions (i.e., the distribution of connectivity values) is different between brain region A and brain region B, noting that (i) each of the 150 connectivity values is measured as a proportion of the total connectivity (so, the 150 connectivity values are not independent), and (ii) the connectivity values for regions A and B are paired (i.e., they are measured from the same subject)? i considered using a one-way repeated-measures multivariate analysis of variance (MANOVA), but i am not sure if this is appropriate given the dependent variables (150 connectivity values) are expressed as proportions.
2. assuming the test above shows an overall difference between region A and B, what would be the most appropriate post-hoc test to compare every one of the 150 connectivity values between region A and B? would paired t-tests (performed for each of the 150 connectivity values) be sufficient, or is it inappropriate given that the connectivity values are expressed as proportions out of the total and so aren't independent?

Comment: You have compositional data, so maybe look into a logratio transform?